# Chrome 64.0.3282.119 cannot support the 'module' function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

This question is about Javascript ES6's module. I have `index.html` and `utils.js` in the same directory in my local drive:

index.html:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
      <script type="module">
         import {addTextToBody} from './utils.js';
         addTextToBody('Modules are pretty cool.');
      </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

utils.js

```
export function addTextToBody(text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

When I launched index.html with Microsoft Edge (Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0), the dialog box was popped out as expected. However, using Chrome did not work at all. According to Mozilla, [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) & [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) have been in support since Chrome 61, so I am confused.

Is this a compatibility issue, or did something go wrong with my code? Any comment or suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Open the developer tools in chrome using `F12` and rerun your page. If you are running locally, you are likely getting a 'CORS' error.

Comment: @Phillip Thomas Many thanks. You're right. I set up a http server that manages both files. Then I used Chrome to retrive the html file and the dialog box was popped out. This indicated my previous attempt should be a CORS error, as you pointed out. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem! I've created an answer just to summarize.

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer tools in chrome using F12 and rerun your page. If you are running locally, you are likely getting a 'CORS' error.

Running a simple web server should solve this issue.